# Factorizing degree four polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Please help me to factorize $x^4+3x^3+6x+10$ completely over $\Bbb{Q}$

I have tried setting the equation equal to $(x+a)(x^3+bx^2+cx+d)$ and comparing the coefficients, but I seem to have too many variables to determine the values of $a,b,c,d$.

I'd appreciate if someone could help with providing the solution to this problem.  Thanks.

Comment: This method only works if you know a root (the value of $a$). ;)

Comment: I have edited your question to make the math more readable.  Look at the edits and this brief tutorial to learn how to use MathJax to make your mathematical expressions/equations look spiffy.  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Double check that there is not a typo in one of the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), if $r$ is a *rational* root of the polynomial
$$
p(x) = x^4 + 3x^3 + 6x + 10,
$$
then
$$
r = \frac{a}{b} \qquad \text{where } \gcd(a, b) = 1 \text{ and }a \mid 10 \text{ and } b \mid 1.
$$
Therefore, the rational candidates are:
$$
\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 5, \pm 10
$$

**EDIT:**
<strike>*Hint:*  at least one of those is actually a root.</strike>

<strike>Once</strike> ${\color{red}{\text{If}}}$ you find a root $r$, you can factor out the linear polynomial $(x - r)$, either by using [Polynomial Long Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) or, preferably, by using [Synthetic Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division).

Comment: Also, if you've discussed Descartes' "Rule of Signs", you'll find that you don't need to waste time checking for _positive_ rational roots.

Comment: it doesnt seem like any of these are roots of the polynomial

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I have corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Irreductibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ iff irreductibility over $\mathbb{Z}$, this is what states the Gauss lemma.

1   If the polynomial has a factor of degree one, then it has a root in $\mathbb{Z}$

2   For factors of degree two. Use your method to determine the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Use this lemma: 
If x = p/q is a rational root of (an x^n + ... + a0) with a0...an integers and p and q coprimes then
p divide a0 and q divide an

In this problem an = 1 and a0 = 10, so x mus be in +-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
Replace x by those numbers and check whether p(x) = 0.

Once you have found a root divide by (x-x1) and so on...

Comment: it must be $\pm1,2,5,10$